# Get a ComPtr<IStream> from a IBuffer

Tags: c++, windows, com, std, uwp

I am struggling at connecting two APIs. From one I get a `Windows::Storage::IBuffer`, and the other demands a `ComPtr<IStream>.` I do not seem to find a way to bridge these two, even if I wanted to do a copy of the data in the stream.

So far the only way forward from IBuffer is to create a `Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader::FromBuffer(buffer).` From there, I can `ReadBytes` to get `Platform::Array<unsigned char>` array, but then what?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming this is the olden COM IStream, it isn't very clear, you'll need to write a class that implements the interface.  You can return E_NOTIMPL for most IStream methods, you need QI, AddRef, Release, Read and (probably) Stat.  The Read method implementation can use DataReader to do the reading.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other methods to get a COM compatible [`IStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034(v=vs.85).aspx) interface for the IBuffer but if you have the data bytes you can create a COM IStream on memory using the [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980(v=vs.85).aspx) API then copying the bytes into the new IStream. Don't forget to reset the seek pointer before handing it out.

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern int CreateStreamOnHGlobal(IntPtr hGlobal, bool fDeleteOnRelease, out IStream ppstm);

System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes stm;
if (CreateStreamOnHGlobal(IntPtr.Zero, true, out stm) == 0)
{
    stm.Write( ...data for the stream... );

    stm.Seek(0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);  // seek to start of stream
}
```